# SharpPcap 4.2 with WinPcap 4.1.3 gives "Unable to open offline adapter: bad dump file format"

Tags: c#, .net, sharppcap

I'm trying to read a pcap file that was created with TShark 1.10.6 with libpcap version 1.4.0 on FreeBSD 9.2, and am doing this on Windows 7 with c# in Visual Studio, SharpPcap 4.2, PacketDotNet 0.13 and WinPcap 4.1.3.

The exception being raised is *Unable to open offline adapter: bad dump file format*, and it occurs in the routine CaptureFileReaderDevice at line:

```
IntPtr adapterHandle = LibPcapSafeNativeMethods.pcap_open_offline( captureFilename, errbuf);
```

What's interesting, is that Wireshark Version 1.10.3 on the same system -- and is also using the same version of WinPcap, is able to open the file!

What would cause SharpPcap to be unable to open this file?

**EDIT #1:**

I looked more closely at WireShark's version information, and apparently it's using a version of WinPcap *without* AirPcap support.  I believe SharpPcap includes AirPcap, so I wonder if that somehow makes a difference.

> Running on 64-bit Windows 7 Service Pack 1, build 7601, with WinPcap
>   version
>   4.1.3 (packet.dll version 4.1.0.2980), based on libpcap version 1.0 branch 1_0_rel0b (20091008), GnuTLS 2.12.18, Gcrypt 1.4.6, without
>   AirPcap.

Also, I'm compiling for a 32-bit output.

**EDIT #2:**

Using WireShark's *Statistics / Summary* for the pcap, it displays the following about the capture:

- OS: FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p10
- Capture application: Dumpcap 1.10.6 (Git Rev Unknown from unknown)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer** is that the originating server is generating *pcap-ng* capture files, and that format is not currently supported by WinPcap, therefore SharpPcap cannot open those files.  The current version of Wireshark, however, does support pcap-ng capture files.

**The gory details** of what led me to that answer:

I found the [Libpcap File Format](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) in the Wireshark docs, and according to the Global Header section, I've got a dump file containing the *magic number* 0x4d3c2b1a (as displayed on my Windows 7 system).

The doc says:

> For nanosecond-resolution files, the writing application writes 0xa1b23c4d, 
>   with the two nibbles of the two lower-order bytes swapped, and the reading 
>   application will read either 0xa1b23c4d (identical) or 0x4d3cb2a1 (swapped).

None of these match this magic number, so I ran the `file` command for the pcap file on the originating FreeBSD system and it reported:

> em0.pcap: pcap-ng capture file - version 1.0

So I took a look at */usr/share/misc/magic* on that server and found the pcap-ng entry:

```
#
# "pcap-ng" capture files.
# http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html
# Pcap-ng files can contain multiple sections. Printing the endianness,
# snaplen, or other information from the first SHB may be misleading.
#
0       ubelong         0x0a0d0d0a
>8      ubelong         0x1a2b3c4d      pcap-ng capture file
>>12    beshort         x               - version %d
>>14    beshort         x               \b.%d
0       ulelong         0x0a0d0d0a
>8      ulelong         0x1a2b3c4d      pcap-ng capture file
>>12    leshort         x               - version %d
>>14    leshort         x               \b.%d
```

Which pointed me to the [PCAP Dump File Format](http://www.winpcap.org/ntar/draft/PCAP-DumpFileFormat.html) (see the Section Header Block description).

And *hexdump* of the pcap file showed:

```
0000000 0d0a 0a0d 0070 0000 3c4d 1a2b 0001 0000
0000010 ffff ffff ffff ffff 0003 0017 7246 6565
0000020 5342 2044 2e39 2d32 4552 454c 5341 2d45
```

which confirms that:

1. this is indeed, a *next-generation* pcap file -- as the block header starts with Block Type = 0x0A0D0D0A (displayed as 0d0a 0a0d), and
2. the header contains the *pcap-ng* magic number 0x1a2b3c4d (displayed as 3c4d 1a2b).

Comment: Great find, Alan. But what do we do?

Comment: @Irwin: I believe we had to modify the process which was generating the pcap-ng file format on FreeBSD 9 to use the old pcap file format.

Answer (score 0):

Copy WinPcap DLLs from [this package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpcap413-176/) to your application folder. It should solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a short term measure, I downloaded the latest version of Wireshark (v2.0) and opened then save the file as Redhat 6.1 *.tcpdump and SharpPcap read it fine.